# React Native: Image inside flexDirection column inside flexDirection row

Tags: ios, image, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to put an image inside a view with flexDirection column, and this view inside another view with flexDirection row. This is the result that I want:

[image]

And this is the result that I get:

[image]

The width of the image should be the same as the width of the blue text. But don't know why the image is bigger than the view it's inside. Here is my code:

```
  <View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>

      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'column', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>

        <Image
          style={{flex: 3, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
          source={require('../img/2.jpg')}
          resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}
        />

        <Text style={{flex: 1}}>24/06/2017</Text>

      </View>

      <View style={{flex: 2}}/>
    </View>

  </View>
```

This part is used to simulate the View of the content.

```
<View style={{flex: 2}}/>
```

I'm running it on iOS.

Comment: I'm not familiar with flex on the phone, but have you tried making it so the flex numbers match on Image and Text?

Comment: If I put flex 1 on Image the result is the same.

Comment: The only way I could get the result tha I wanted was changing flexDirection:'column' to flexDirection:'row', and the Image fits the View, but doing this I can't put the Text in the bottom of the Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo9x2.png)

Also Add Dimensions as shown below

```
var {
  Dimensions

} = React;
```

try this way you need to set height and width of the image :

```
<View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height:200 }}>

          <View style={{ flexDirection:'column', backgroundColor: 'blue', height:100 , width: 100}}>

            <Image
              style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height:100 , width: 100}}
              source={require('./img/2.jpg')}
              resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}
            />
             <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>24/06/2017</Text>


          </View> 
        </View>

      </View>
```

below is the code gives you the width of the mobile layout now change you width and height according to mobile device width
For Example :

```
width : deviceWidth/3,
height : deviceHeight/3
```

instead of static given height and width.
you can give height and width according to your requiredment now.

i hope you understand.

```
var deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

Comment: yes, this work but I wanted to the image size fits the view size, so the image should change according to the phone screen size.

Comment: I could get the view.width size and make some math to make the image stay in the size I want, but I don't  think it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: Hello brenoxp, i Update my answer.Hope this may help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the `<View style={{flex: 2}}/>`.  I think this empty view is on the same row as the `flex='row'` and is preventing your text from extending across the screen.

Comment: Actualy in <View style={{flex: 2}}/> I'm just creating and empty component to simulate the size of the content on the right. My problem is with the Image size that over fit the View it's inside.